# A way to send low memory warning to app on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks, low-memory

I'm looking for some tool/app/tweak that can generate low memory warning on iPhone (jailbroken). Or, as alternative variant - tweak that simulates high memory usage.

I need it to test my app behavior on low memory warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can test this on the Simulator, thru the "*Simulate Memory Warning*" menu item (from the "*Hardware*" menu)
- On your device, you can call the private method `_performMemoryWarning`

  ```
  #if DEBUG
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(_performMemoryWarning)];
  #endif
  ```
- Another solution is to send the notification manually too:

  ```
  CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), (CFStringRef)@"UISimulatedMemoryWarningNotification", NULL, NULL, true);
  ```

Comment: The notification option is the one that I don't know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you are running the app on simulator, you can do it by:

> Hardware (on top menu) -> Simulate Memory Warning

And for real device you can do it with a private method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(_performMemoryWarning)];
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Swift:

```
UIApplication.shared.perform(Selector(("_performMemoryWarning")))
```